# How to record from keyboard to laptop?

Tags: audio-recording, software, techniques, cable, piano

I have a electronic piano/keboard ( Yamaha PSR E323 ) and I am planning to record myself playing a piece. My laptop, to which I will be recording to is a Lenevo Z570 .

I am a newbie in in this area and I do not have any knowledge of the technical aspects nor do I have any MIDI cables/soundcard etc.

I understand that I have to buy some cables, and some other stuff .. so I would like your help very much on what to do. I have quite a low budget .. less than $20.Also, I use Ubuntu and I wouldn't like to use any paid software.

It would be very much help if you could suggest me the cables to buy, how to use them and what softwares to use. ( I already googled for these things but couldn't find anything useful )

Comment: This does not appear to be sound design related.  This site is for sound designers and audio engineers, it is not targeted at musicians.

Comment: I understand that this is not a fully sound design related question .. it is more about the technique of recording sound. Of all the Stack Exchange sites present, I found this one to be more appropriate than the other sites for this question. But if the admins and mods think that this question can be answered better in some other Stack Exchange site, I request you to please migrate this question to that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an USB MIDI Interface. Cheap ones are available at $15. It is used to send the data which keys are played to the computer, then the computer can store these data and also send it back to the keyboard to replay it. You also need a software to record, process and replay the MIDI data. That software is called a MIDI sequencer but today its common to say DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) or Host. There are several free DAW available for Linux, f.e. Rosegarden. To find out more about hosts you should check out kvraudio.com - they have also a forum where people will friendly help you with music related questions. Btw. be aware that getting everything to work on Linux can sometimes be difficult, especially with not so common hardware.